# Libre Office custom Dialog Table

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic, openoffice-basic

I am creating a custom Dialog where the user is supposed to select one of multiple possible entries. I use a List Box to list the possible entries to be selected from.

There are multiple variables for each row, therefore I would like to use a table to properly align the entries. Is there a possibility to do so?

What i have:

```
abcdefg hijkl mnopq
abcd efghijk lmno
```

What i want:

```
abcdefg   hijkl      mnopq
abcd      efghilkl   mno
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a fixed-width font for the list box, and pad the strings with spaces.

```vb
Sub PaddedListboxItems
    oListBox.addItems(Array(
        PaddedItem(Array("abcdefg", "hijkl", "mnopq")),
        PaddedItem(Array("abcd", "efghijk", "lmno"))), 0)
End Sub

Function PaddedItem(item_strings As Array)
    PaddedItem = PadString(item_strings(0), 10) & _
        PadString(item_strings(1), 11) & item_strings(2)
End Function

Function PadString(strSource As String, lPadLen As Long)
    PadString = strSource & " "
    If Len(strSource) < lPadLen Then
        PadString = strSource & Space(lPadLen - Len(strSource))
    End If
End Function
```

More ways to pad strings in Basic are at http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=522164, although not all of them work in LibreOffice Basic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

Create a new dialog and at the bottom, add a label.
Create a new module and add following code:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Dim oDialog1 As Object, oDataModel As Object, oListener As Object

Sub OpenDialog()
    Dim oGrid As Object, oGridModel As Object, oColumnModel As Object, oCol As Object
    Dim oLabel1 As Object, rect(3) As Integer

    DialogLibraries.LoadLibrary("Standard")
    oDialog1 = CreateUnoDialog(DialogLibraries.Standard.Dialog1)
    oGridModel = oDialog1.getModel().createInstance("com.sun.star.awt.grid.UnoControlGridModel")

    oLabel1 = oDialog1.getModel().getByName("Label1")
    rect(0) = oLabel1.getPropertyValue("PositionX")
    rect(1) = 10
    rect(2) = oLabel1.getPropertyValue("Width")
    rect(3) = oLabel1.getPropertyValue("PositionY") - 2*rect(1)
    With oGridModel
        .PositionX = rect(0)
        .PositionY = rect(1)
        .Width = rect(2)
        .Height = rect(3)
    End With

    oColumnModel = oGridModel.ColumnModel
    oCol = oColumnModel.createColumn()
    oCol.Title = "Column 1"
    oColumnModel.addColumn(oCol)

    oCol = oColumnModel.createColumn()
    oCol.Title = "Column 2"
    oColumnModel.addColumn(oCol)

    oCol = oColumnModel.createColumn()
    oCol.Title = "Column 3"
    oColumnModel.addColumn(oCol)

    oDialog1.getModel().insertByName("grid", oGridModel)
    oGrid = oDialog1.getControl("grid")
    oListener = (CreateUnoListener("grid_", "com.sun.star.awt.grid.XGridSelectionListener"))
    oGrid.addSelectionListener(oListener)

    oDataModel = oGridModel.GridDataModel
    oDataModel.addRow("a", Array("abcdefg", "hijkl", "mnopq"))
    oDataModel.addRow("b", Array("abcd", "efghijk", "lmno"))

    oDialog1.execute()
    oDialog1.dispose()
End Sub
```

To get the values of the selected row, add a listener for the `grid_selectionChanged` event:

```
Sub grid_selectionChanged(ev)
    Dim oRows() As Object, oLabel1 As Object, sCells(2) As String
    oRows = ev.Source.getSelectedRows()
    oLabel1 = oDialog1.getModel().getByName("Label1")
    sCells(0) = oDataModel.getRowData(oRows(0))(0)
    sCells(1) = oDataModel.getRowData(oRows(0))(1)
    sCells(2) = oDataModel.getRowData(oRows(0))(2)
    oLabel1.setPropertyValue("Label", "Selected values: " + sCells(0) + "," + sCells(1) + "," + sCells(2))
End Sub
```

If you did all correctly, by running `OpenDialog` you should get your grid:

[image]